# AWS EC2 connection from DHCP cleint

Tags: amazon-ec2

Can any one help me out on this issue ....

My office network is in DHCP and as per IT support team it is not possible for them to disclose all the pools as those are huge in number and security reason.

In that case how can I connect my EC2 instances? I mean in security group I can not specify the IP address/range as in DHCP and range are unknown on the other hand I do not want to  add 0.0.0.0/0 in security group for security reason.

Other than adding IP in security group is there any other way , any work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using your internal network IP, you should be using the firewall/gateway IP address that your company has. Google [whats my ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=whats+my+ip) and Google will tell you (at least one of) your external IP addresses. That's what you should be using in the security group.

And, of course, that works great until you're working offsite one day...